# How to read csv with second line as header in pyspark dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, dataframe, pyspark

I am trying to load a csv and make the second line as header. How to achieve this. Please let me know. Thanks.

```
file_location = "/mnt/test/raw/data.csv"
file_type = "csv"    

infer_schema = "true"
delimiter = ","

data = spark.read.format(file_type) \
  .option("inferSchema", infer_schema) \
  .option("header", "false") \
  .option("sep", delimiter) \
  .load(file_location) \
```

Comment: Does your first line look different than the others? if so how?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First Read the data as rdd and then pass this rdd to df.read.csv()

```
data=sc.TextFile('/mnt/test/raw/data.csv')
firstRow=data.first()
data=data.filter(lambda row:row != firstRow)
df = spark.read.csv(data,header=True)
```

For reference of dataframe functions use the below link, This would serve as bible for all of the dataframe operations you need, for specific version of spark replace "latest" in url to whatever version you want:

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html

Comment: Thanks. It worked.  `data=sc.textFile('/mnt/test/raw/data.csv')`

Comment: Where does the sc.TextFile comes from?